# convert curl to guzzle

Tags: php, curl, guzzle

i have this perfectly working curl command:

`curl -i --data "site=walletgroove.com&placement=above&device=desktop&source=*&campaign=*&url=*&country=*&active=1" http://10.0.0.38/adserver/src/public/api/rule`

which i tried to execute with guzzle but for some reason i keep getting error from my code, an exception to be more accurate. this exception is thrown when params are not passed properly. 
this is one of few tries i had:

```
public function testApi_postRule()
{
    $client = new Client();

    $client->post('http://10.0.0.38/adserver/src/public/api/rule',[ 'query' => [
         'site' => 'walletgroove.com',
         'placement' => 'guzzle_unique_placement',
         'device' => 'desktop',
         'source' => 'guzzource',
         'campaign' => '*',
         'country' => '*',
         'url' => '*',
         'active' => '1'
        ]]);
    }
```

any idea what am i doing wrong here??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing the `query` parameter, which appends a query string instead of sending in the request body. For a POST request, you probably want to use `form_params` as shown in the [documentation](https://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#sending-form-fields).

```
$client->post('http://10.0.0.38/adserver/src/public/api/rule', [
    'form_params' => [
        'site' => 'walletgroove.com',
        'placement' => 'guzzle_unique_placement',
        'device' => 'desktop',
        'source' => 'guzzource',
        'campaign' => '*',
        'country' => '*',
        'url' => '*',
        'active' => '1'
    ]
]);
```